# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while trying to run PGDSpider

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run the bioinformatics software [PGDSpider](http://www.cmpg.unibe.ch/software/PGDSpider/#Download_and_Installation_Instructions). Installation instructions are pretty straightforward:

1. Installing the Java7 RE.
2. Downloading the PGDSpider application.
3. Executing the command `bash ./PGDSpider2.sh`.

However when I try to execute the program an error appears related to Java that I don't quite understand:

```
luis@luis-Inspiron-5570:PGDSpider_2.1.1.5$ bash PGDSpider2.sh
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:861)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:773)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:901)
    at ch.unibe.iee.cmpg.pgdspider.PGDSpider.main(PGDSpider.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ls.DocumentLS
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 15 more
```

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 and have the following version of Java:

```
(bioinfo) luis@luis-Inspiron-5570:PGDSpider_2.1.1.5$ java -version
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Any help will be pretty much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Error was solved by following the next steps:

1. Downgrading Java to Java 8:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre`

2. Manually switching to this older version of java:

```
(bioinfo) luis@luis-Inspiron-5570:PGDSpider_2.1.1.5$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1411      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1411      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
```

3. Executing PGDSpider2 script

`bash PGDSpider2.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PGDSpider, so you're going to have to do some fiddling about in the `PGDSpider2.sh` script, but you should see a line that reads something akin to:

```
java PGDSpider2.jar
```

That line should be changed to the following:

```
java --add-modules java.se.ee -jar PGDSpider2.jar
```

Again, my fix may not be perfect, so feel free to add comments which might provide more insight (such as the exact text of `PGDSpider2.sh`). The latest versions of Java SDK no longer include certain Java EE modules by default, and it looks like your tool was built when those modules were included. The strategy here is just to make them available again.

Comment: `PGDSpider2.sh` is a very simple script it runs `java` command on the `PGDSpider2.jar` file: 
`java -Xmx1024m -Xms512m -jar PGDSpider2.jar `

Comment: I have edited that script both by adding the flags it had with the ones you suggest and also by replacing them completely. In both cases the same error occurred: `Error occurred during initialization of boot layer. java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found`

Comment: Please post the output of `java -version` from your console. I suspect you have Java 11 or newer, which means you don't have java.se.ee at all. You'll probably have to downgrade Java to work with PGDSpider (Java 7, 8, 9 or 10 should be OK as per PGDSpider doc).

Comment: Yes, I do have a newer version of Java:

`openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: Yeah... you'll have to downgrade until PGDSpider is refactored to no longer depend on that module. Moving back to Java 7 should let you run with the standard script. Java 8-10 will require the add-modules flag.

Comment: I don't have Java 7 installed, however manually switching to Java 8 solved the issue and PGDSpider worked correctly. Even without the add-modules flag. Thanks!